# How should I interpret the sampling theorem?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I recently learned the following:

> **Theorem:** If $f(t)$ is a band-limited signal with cut-off frequency $\Omega/2\pi$, then
>   $$
> f(t) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} f\left(\frac{n\pi}{\Omega}\right) \operatorname{sinc}(\Omega t - n\pi)
> $$

Of all the things I've seen in Fourier analysis, this is by far the strangest. For some reason, I'm having trouble deriving any substantial *meaning* from this formula, other than the fact that $f$ can be "recovered" from its values at certain intervals.

I really don't understand this intuitively like I do other things, like the Fourier series or Fourier transform. Why can we do this if $f$ is band-limited, and why would "band-limitedness" be the condition that allows this to occur? How should I interpret the $\text{sinc}$'s? This is all just very confusing and meaningless to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we sample $f$ at the points $x_n = n T$. How can we recover the full function $f$, given only these sample values?

The key idea (a brilliant idea) is to recognize that sampling $f$ at these particular values is equivalent to multiplying $f$ by a [Dirac comb function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) $g_T$ which has an infinitely sharp spike of unit area at each point $x_n$. Here's a visualization of a Dirac comb from Wikipedia:

$\qquad \qquad$[image]

Let
$$
h = g_T \cdot f.
$$
By "equivalent", I mean that knowing the values of $f$ at the points $x_n$ is equivalent to knowing the function $h$.

Of course, the most important fact about the Fourier transform is that multiplication in the time domain corresponds to convolution in the frequency domain. Moreover, it can be shown that the [Fourier transform of a comb function is a comb function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898432/the-fourier-transform-of-a-comb-function-is-a-comb-function). Thus, 
$$
\hat h = \hat g_T * \hat f = \frac{1}{T} g_{\frac{1}{T}} * \hat f.
$$
What happens when you convolve with a comb function, as we are doing here?  If you visualize the graph of $g_{\frac{1}{T}} * \hat f$, it consists of a bunch of shifted copies of the graph of $\hat f$. If we assume that $f$ is sufficiently band-limited, then crucially *these copies do not overlap*, which is very nice because we are now able to recover $\hat f$ exactly by multiplying $\hat h$ by a "[rectangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function)" $\hat r$:
$$
\hat f = \hat r \cdot \left( g_{\frac{1}{T}} * f \right) = \hat r \cdot (T \hat h).
$$
Here's a picture from Wikipedia that illustrates this idea nicely:
[image]

Now we are ready to recover $f$ by taking the inverse Fourier transform of both sides:
$$
\tag{$\spadesuit$} f = r * (T h).
$$
We can now see where the sinc function comes from, because the inverse Fourier transform of the rectangular function $\hat r$ is the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function#Fourier_transform_of_the_rectangular_function). Equation ($\spadesuit$) expresses $f$ as a sum of shifted copies of the sinc function, with each copy weighted by the corresponding sample value of $f$. Written out explicitly, we have discovered the formula for $f(t)$ given above in the question statement.